# left join when results may or may not be in table

Tags: mysql

From my understanding of how a join works, it creates as many combinations as it can. A left join can create a combination with null if the value isn't present. The problem I am having is the following friend and gifting system.

- User #2 has friends 3 and 4
- User #2 has a gift already out there for user 3
- User #2 has no gift for #4

When I run the below query, it can only find the friendship to #4 in one of 2 cases. Either there are no gifts in the table, in which case it returns back both friends with NULLs for the gift values, or every friend has at least one gift. What I need it to do is return back every friend along with their last gift or null if they have never given one.

Table structure:

- Users-> A list of users with names
- friends-> A list of relationships between 2 users(1 user is the originator of the friendship and the other is the destination)
- gifts-> A list of gifts given from one user to another

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
JOIN friends ON (friends.originator = 2 OR friends.destination = 2)// Find the friendships I am in
LEFT JOIN gifts ON (gifts.originator = 2)//Find all gifts where I sent the gift
WHERE users.name != 2 // filter out the users who are not me
and (gifts.originator IS NULL OR gifts.destination = users.name)//allow null gifts or gifts to the mentioned users
GROUP BY gifts.destination // show 1 gift per friend
ORDER BY gifts.time ASC//show only the latest gift
```

Comment: so you need all possible combinations of records from all users (except 2), friends (with originator = 2) and gifts (with originator = 2 ), and then filter and leave just the ones with `gifts.destination = users.name`? as for me this makes little sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
JOIN friends ON (friends.originator = 2 OR friends.destination = 2)// Find the friendships I am in
LEFT JOIN gifts ON friends.originator = gifts.originator and gifts.destination = users.name) //Find all gifts where I sent the gift
WHERE users.name != 2 // filter out the users who are not me
GROUP BY gifts.destination // show 1 gift per friend
ORDER BY gifts.time ASC//show only the latest gift
```

Hope that is what you need.

Comment: I had to tweak some of the outlying clauses but the overall change to the LEFT JOIN seems to have done the trick. I will post again if I find any corner cases that this does not work for. Thanks!